# Apache Camel exchange body to URI query parameters

Tags: post, apache-camel, query-string

I have an apache camel route that is making an HTTP POST request i.e.

```
from(...).setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant(POST)).to("http4://myUrl?...");
```

The request URL includes query params (unusual for POST i know, but I have no choice here) that I need to populate from details of the exchange which are stored on the body.

i.e. The body is a POJO like so:

```
public class Params {
    String param1;
    int param2;
    ....
    //etc. etc. including getters and setters
}
```

Where each field is either a primitive or string, and refers directly to an equivalent query parameter:

```
http4://myUrl?param1=...&param2=...&...
```

Is there a way I can avoid having to manually define every parameter on the URL and instead automagically map the exchange body to query params on the request being made?

The reason I need to do this is that some of the query params are optional, and should be populated based on the contents of the exchange body.

Comment: You can set the header Exchange.HTTP_QUERY with the query parameters separated by &

Comment: That's still manual, i was wondering if there's a way to object map to body to query params without me having to specify each one in code. If not that's a nice way of doing it, thanks.

Comment: No there is no magic automatic mapping of a message body fields to query parameters.

Comment: Thanks Claus (aka the Camel Oracle), if you want add the above two comments as a proper answer and i'll mark it as accepted for the bounty if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the header Exchange.HTTP_QUERY with the query parameters separated.

And its not possible to automatic map from a message bodies its fields to URI parameters (no magic included). You would need to build some code that computes the URI query with `&` separating the values, and setting that as the `HTTP_QUERY` header.